# Neither rspec or database_cleaner will roll back my tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

For reasons I cannot figure out, my database is not getting cleaned after each test.
I was relying on 
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

But that wasn't working, so I went with database_cleaner, but that's not working also.

I've configured database cleaner according to the readme:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :deletion
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.around(:each) do |example|
    DatabaseCleaner.cleaning do
      example.run
    end
  end
end
```

But this test fails:

```
describe "db_cleaner" do
    it "should clean db" do
      FactoryGirl.create :question
      expect(Question.all.count).to eq(1)
    end
end
```

with

```
Failure/Error: expect(Question.all.count).to eq(1)
expected: 1
got: 7
```

(and got continues to increment each time)

I'm invoking the test with

```
bin/rspec spec/models/concerns/results_compiler_spec.rb:12
```

I'm running

```
rspec-rails 2.99.0
rails 4.2.0
factory_girl_rails 4.5.0
database_cleaner 1.4.1
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I never did find an answer to this on this particular project, but I came across it in a recent project and discovered it was because I'd forgotton to include

```
require 'rails_helper'
```

in my spec.

(Specs with it were cleaning fine, specs without were not)